# Como manter um repositório git atualizado com outro?

Tags: git, github, repository

Participo de dois repositórios no GitHub, sendo o segundo um clone do primeiro, e por enquanto privado (por questões de segurança).

Clonei este segundo em minha máquina para poder trabalhar em cima, mas além dos meus próprios commits também preciso mantê-lo atualizado com o primeiro.

Estou estudando sobre o `git remote`, pois se entendi bem um `git remote update` daria conta do recado, porém me restam algumas dúvidas, por exemplo:

1 - Essa é mesmo a melhor alternativa para manter um repo atualizado com outro? (sendo necessário que o segundo seja privado)

2 - Se eu der um `git remote add` para linkar o primeiro repo neste privado, e atualizá-lo, ao dar um `push` corro o risco de enviar para o primeiro (público)? Porque isso não pode ocorrer.

[image: Diagrama]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você tem um fork privado, você provavelmente o clonou assim:

`$ git clone git@github.com:<user>/priv.git`

O repositório padrão da sua cópia é, portanto, `git@github.com:<user>/priv.git` (chamada de `origin`), e é para onde você envia seus commits quando dá um `git push`.

Para adicionar um novo remote - chamemos ele de `xyz123` (pode ser qualquer coisa) - você executa o comando:

`$ git remote add xyz123 git@github.com:<otheruser>/public.git`

Note que as urls podem ser diferentes se você estiver usando, por exemplo, https.

A partir disso, o comando `git pull xyz123` atualizará sua cópia local com as últimas atualizações do repositório `xyz123` que você adicionou. Enquanto isso,  `git push` irá continuar enviando commits para a sua branch padrão (no caso, `origin`). Porém se quiser você também pode enviar seus commits para `xyz123` através de `git push xyz123`.

Note que o comando `pull` tem o mesmo comportamento: `git pull` somente atualizará a sua cópia local com as atualizações do repositório padrão (normalmente `origin`). Para atualizar com outros repositórios você precisa especificar qual deles (no caso, `git pull xyz123`).

1. Essa é a melhor alternativa para manter seu repo privado atualizado. Você sempre faz `pull` das mudanças em `xyz123` e as envia para `origin`, os sincronizando.
2. Você só vai enviar commits para o seu novo remote `xyz123` se especificar explicitamente em seu comando `push`. Caso não especificar nada, o commit irá para o repositório padrão (normalmente `origin`).